# how to make combine Gregorian and Islamic(Hijri) calendar in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, gregorian-calendar, hijri

In my iOS app there is there is combine Gregorian and Islamic(Hijri) calendar in UI.

Something like below screenshot -
[combine Gregorian and Islamic(Hijri) calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N3e4.png)

First, I go through [cocoapods Calendar's](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=calendar).
There several examples for calendar there.

But i have no idea how i will implement calendar according to my requirement.

Please help me for it.

Comment: I too look for this question, if you know the answer please help me.